# Issue receiving a response using AJAX, jQuery and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I am trying to figure out how to send values and receive the right response.
The only response that I can seem to get is 0.

This is the AJAX and form I am sending with:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(':submit').on('click', function() { 
    var email = $("#txtEmail").val();
    var password = $("#txtPassword").val();
    $.ajax({ // ajax call starts
      url: 'isValid.php',
      data: {'email': $("#txtEmail").val(),
             'password': $("#txtPassword").val()
             },
      dataType: 'json', // Choosing a JSON datatype
    })
    .done(function(data) {
       $('#valid').html(data);

   });
    return false;     
  });
});

</script>



<form method="post" action="">
     Email:<br/>
     <input id="txtEmail" name="txtEmail" type=text/><br/>
     Password:<br/>
     <input id="txtPassword" name="txtPassword" type=text/><br/>
     <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
     <input type="reset" value="Clear"/>
</form>
<div id="valid"></div>
```

This is the php script I am using to try and send the response back:

```
<?php

$email = $_GET["login"];
$pass = $_GET["password"];

print json_encode($email + " " + $pass);
?>
```

All I am getting back is a 0 and am not sure why.

Comment: Wrong get names. `'email': $("#txtEmail").val()`. Password should be working...

Comment: Thank you, can't believe I missed that one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thats because you are concatenating wrongly your response, and you have wrong parameters in your get:

```
<?php

$email = $_GET["email"];
$pass = $_GET["password"];

print json_encode($email . " " . $pass);
?>
```

Comment: It worked! I actually tried that while I was trying to figure it out but it was while I was trying it without the json_encode but went back to the + signs when it obvisouly didn't work. Thanks a lot!